# Creating a 2D Co-Ordinate plane in Java using for loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, 2d, plane

I am trying to create a program CoordinateFinder.java that asks the user two integer values between 1 and 5. Then, use a pair of for loops to produce a 2D coordinate plane. The plane should print a period for every coordinate on the plane except for the one specified by the user, which should print an X.

Example of what I am trying to do:

```
Enter your x coordinate: 
2
Enter your y coordinate: 
4

5 . . . . . 
4 . X . . . 
3 . . . . . 
2 . . . . . 
1 . . . . . 
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

What I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CoordinateFinder {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter an X co-ordinate from 1-5: ");
int x = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please enter a y co-ordinate from 1-5:  ");
int y = input.nextInt();


for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
    System.out.print(i +" ");
    if (i == 0) {
        System.out.println("\n");
        System.out.println(" 5 4 3 2 1 ");  
    }
    for (int j = 4; j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(" . ");
        if (j == 0) {
            System.out.println("\n");

        }
    }
}
}

}
```

Which outputs:

```
5  .  .  .  .  . 

4  .  .  .  .  . 

3  .  .  .  .  . 

2  .  .  .  .  . 

1  .  .  .  .  . 

0 

5 4 3 2 1 
.  .  .  .  .
```

Comment: Is it always a 6 by 6 grid?

Comment: yes it is! @mettleap

Answer (score 1):

In your nested `FOR` loops, the variable `i` represents your `y` value and variable `j` represents your `x` value. So on each `i` loop you need to print the complete row (y-values) and on each 'j' nested loop you determine what is printed in each column (x-value). To determine if you need to print an `X` or a `.` you need to compare `i` and `j` to `y` and `x`, like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoordinateFinder {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter an X co-ordinate from 1-5: ");
    int x = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter a y co-ordinate from 1-5:  ");
    int y = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("");

    for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
        System.out.print(i);

        for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) {
            if (i == y && j == x) {
                System.out.print(" X");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" .");
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\n");
    }

    System.out.println("0 1 2 3 4 5");
}

}
```

Output:

```
Please enter an X co-ordinate from 1-5: 
2
Please enter a y co-ordinate from 1-5:  
4

5 . . . . .
4 . X . . .
3 . . . . .
2 . . . . .
1 . . . . .
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Please note that I did reverse the direction of `j` in the subloop to represent the increasing x-values as you traverse from left to right on the grid. I left `i` decrementing to represent the decreasing y-values as you traverse down the rows. The rest of my changes were formatting.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense. So it would not matter that we are printing the X rows labels just as a print function? {System.out.println("0 1 2 3 4 5");}

Comment: @IanHank It should only matter if the grid can be a different size. You can't print the last line as you go, but you could create another FOR loop outside of the original (at the end) to loop through an incrementing variable and print the numbers.